# Increasing lanes for Grid Scenario

Tags: flow-project

I am trying to modify Grid Scenario template. When changing horizontal_lanes and vertical_lanes, the code is working without giving any problem.

The problem is that i could not place vehicles on other lanes. I've got different type of errors everytime when modifying grid.py.

Is there any more generic grid scenario or something else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently doing the same thing.

The first thing you have to take into account is that the phase size of traffic lights is gonna change. Therefore you have to change the traffic light plan (the String sequence) and also `green_wave_env.py` (look for every call to the function `set_state()`). Otherwise you'll get an error saying that there's a problem with the phase size and the 'online' program.

I was able to add cars to the second lane. In order to do so, you just have to modify the call to `vehicles.add()` in `green_wave.py`. I added the options `lane_change_params` and `lane_change_controller`.

Until that it is OK, but now I get warning because vehicles collide every time they want to change lane. 
Hope this will be useful!

```
vehicles.add(
veh_id='idm',
acceleration_controller=(SimCarFollowingController, {}),
car_following_params=SumoCarFollowingParams(
    minGap=2.5,
    max_speed=V_ENTER,
    speed_mode="all_checks",
),
lane_change_params=SumoLaneChangeParams(
    lane_change_mode="strategic",
    model="LC2013",
),
lane_change_controller=(StaticLaneChanger, {}),
routing_controller=(MinicityRouter, {}),
num_vehicles=tot_cars)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have added the following issue to our to-do list: https://github.com/flow-project/flow/issues/682

However, it should be possible for you to modify the base example to add vehicles to the extra lanes. To increase the number of lanes, you need to set vertical_lanes and horizontal_lanes to values greater than 1. However, the base environment for the traffic lights is not intended for more than 1 lane, so you will have to modify the traffic light instructions to make it work. Currently, the environment has it pretty hard-coded in that there is one traffic light per lane so there will definitely be changes you need to make to extend it.
If you do extend it, please open a PR! In the meantime, you can track the progress on the issue I linked.

Eugene

Comment: Thank you for adding issue to to-do list. I will follow it.